# Active Record returns null when aliasing primary_key as "id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to alias DB fields, but aliasing primary_key as "id" will blank its value:

```
class XXX < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'XXX'
  self.primary_key = 'xxx_id'

  def self.get()
    self.select(
        primary_key + ' AS id',
        'xxx_itmno AS product_number',
        'xxx_qty AS qty'
    )
  end
```

Output:

```
[{
  id: null,
  product_number: 123,
  qty: 2
}]
```

**Question 1. What's the easiest way to workaround this issue?**

**Question 2. Why this is happening?**

---

**PS #1:**

The issue goes away if I alias as something else.

i.e. `primary_key + 'AS id_'`, which will output:

```
[{
  id_: 42,
  product_number: 123,
  qty: 2
}]
```

---

**PS #2:**

I find that including PK also will work:

```
self.select(
    primary_key,
    primary_key + ' AS id', ...
```

Output:

```
[{
  xxx_id: 42,
  id: 42,
  product_number: 123,
  qty: 2
}]
```

But, I would have to post-process removing the PK.

Comment: id is the one column where you just have to accept Rails' convention over configuration, if this is for a legacy database you may need to leverage something like Ruby Object Mapper vs. ActiveRecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why this is happening?**

When [ActiveRecord:: AttributeMethods::Read](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb) reads an attribute value, `id` is a special case:

```
def read_attribute(attr_name, &block)
  ...
  name = self.class.primary_key if name == "id".freeze
  _read_attribute(name, &block)
end
```

When you call the method `id`, ActiveRecord will get the value of primary key `xxx_id` which will only be available if `xxx_id` was included in the `select` statement.

**What's the easiest way to workaround this issue?**

It would probably be dangerous to try to override the ActiveRecord `id` logic, since it is likely that Rails code and other gems depend upon it working this way.

If you just need the values back and don't necessarily need to be working with ActiveRecord objects, you could wrap your select statement inside of [select_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all):

```
class XXX < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.get
    select(
      primary_key + ' AS id',
      'xxx_itmno AS product_number',
      'xxx_qty AS qty'
    )
  end

  def self.get_values
    connection.select_all(get)
  end
```

This would return:

```
[{
  "id" => 42,
  "product_number" => 123,
  "qty" => 2
}]
```

If you need them to be ActiveRecord objects, you may need to load the columns without aliases and then use something like `map` to get them into the format you want.